# Возможно ли сделать такую ссылку или кнопку, на которую не смогут нажать роботы?

Tags: html, javascript

Хочу как-нибудь защитить рекламный баннер у себя на сайте, от скликивания.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov: сделайте ответом, а?

Comment: сделал. исходники страницы на хэшкоде много интересного могут рассказать :))

Answer (score 2):

`<a href="#" rel="noindex,nofollow">робот, сюда не ходи, дальше иди, да</a>` [Атрибут rel](http://htmlbook.ru/html/a/rel)

Comment: @Yura Ivanov Я не поисковых роботов, имела ввиду. :) Простите. :)

Comment: @Angelina_Jo: А каких, простите[?](http://lurkmore.to/%D0%9E%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8B)

Comment: @Angelina_Jo, а ну тогда зависит от роботов. Есть такие, от которых не спрячешься никак. Для простых хватит и ссылки с обработчиком в скрипте или капчи (бывают и текстовые, и картиночные и флешевые...). Для сложных, для игр, например, фильтруют ботов эвристикой (частота запросов и т.д.), банят ботоводов. Но чтоб сложный бот не смог, например, ссылку javascript'овую нажать - эт врядли...

Answer (score 0):

сделайте фейковых кнопок, которые не будут видны пользователю, на них будет бот жмакать, так вычислите кто за рулем программа или просто усидчивый чел, страдающий игровой зависимостью :)

Comment: Угу, аж одна проверка на стороне бота.

Comment: обожаю людей с угрюмыми ответами :)

Answer (score 0):

может [так](http://jsfiddle.net/3EqAU/)? С помощью jquery...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/3EqAU/1/
так даже можно обойтись без повторений jQuery, jQuery, jQuery :)

Comment: ботописателям по барабану все эти ухищрения, они работают с get/post запросами. чтоб понять откуда берутся данные, они смотрят код в js, некоторой (может быть довольно сильной) обфускацией им можно усложнить жизнь, но в большинстве случаев самые упорные добиваются успеха и делятся своим ботом (иногда платно).